# about creating a dynamic list view with retrieving from firebase android studio

Tags: android, listview

I faced infinite run when I am trying using ListView with retrieving data from firebase, and I don't know how can I solve it.

My main goal is retrieving from firebase with a dynamic number of clients who have a status of "Not approved".

This my RUN

> 10/03 21:30:58: Launching app $ adb shell am start -n
>   "com.example.atheer.booklyv1/com.example.atheer.booklyv1.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online Connected to
>   process 8309 on device emulator-5554 Capturing and displaying logcat
>   messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the
>   "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
>   W/atheer.booklyv: JIT profile information will not be recorded:
>   profile file does not exits. I/chatty:
>   uid=10086(com.example.atheer.booklyv1) identical 10 lines
>   W/atheer.booklyv: JIT profile information will not be recorded:
>   profile file does not exits. W/atheer.booklyv: Unsupported class
>   loader W/atheer.booklyv: Skipping duplicate class check due to
>   unsupported classloader W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor
>   class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. W/DynamiteModule: Local
>   module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>   W/atheer.booklyv: Verification of android.content.Intent
>   com.google.android.gms.common.zzf.zza(android.content.Context, int,
>   java.lang.String) took 130.356ms I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth:
>   ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
>   D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user (
>   N72Vpxaf6dao4pSf5cvBJ1jwzGo2 ). D/FirebaseApp:
>   com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping
>   initialization. V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -1422956107 V/FA:
>   Registered activity lifecycle callback I/FirebaseInitProvider:
>   FirebaseApp initialization successful I/InstantRun: starting instant
>   run server: is main process V/FA: Collection enabled V/FA: App
>   package, google app id: com.example.atheer.booklyv1,
>   1:666514046827:android:60ad4570c33e1aec I/FA: App measurement is
>   starting up, version: 11910
>         To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>         To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>           adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.atheer.booklyv1 D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found. V/FA: onActivityCreated V/FA:
>   Connecting to remote service I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading
>   module via FirebaseOptions.
>                   [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>   W/atheer.booklyv: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
>   (light greylist, reflection) W/atheer.booklyv: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light
>   greylist, reflection) D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline V/FA:
>   Connection attempt already in progress
>         Activity resumed, time: 1574868 I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state
>   listeners. D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners. D/FA:
>   Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462403}] D/:
>   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdeffec40, tid
>   8354 I/ConfigStore:
>   android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay
>   retrieved: 0
>                  android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay
>   retrieved: 0 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose
>   config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext:
>   0xcc20f240: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xcc20f240: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2730c60) D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2730c60) V/FA:
>   Connection attempt already in progress D/FA: Connected to remote
>   service V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4 V/StudioProfiler:
>   StudioProfilers agent attached. V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring
>   Application for Events V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class:
>   java/net/URL W/atheer.booklyv: Current dex file has more than one
>   class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no
>   transformations are applied to it! V/StudioProfiler: Memory control
>   stream started. V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking disabled.
>   V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking enabled.
>                     JNIEnv not attached V/StudioProfiler: Loaded classes: 11553 V/StudioProfiler: Tracking initialization took:
>   410566000ns W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@f188cbd V/FA: Recording user engagement,
>   ms: 4164 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1579010 V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   I/atheer.booklyv: Background concurrent copying GC freed 662(4MB)
>   AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/6MB, paused
>   1.122ms total 328.178ms D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   engagement_time_msec(_et)=4164,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462403}] V/FA: Activity resumed,
>   time: 1580197 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=5185910341027462403,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=mHomePage,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462404}] D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2730c60)
>   W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token
>   android.os.BinderProxy@877a26c V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms:
>   4828 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1585022 V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   engagement_time_msec(_et)=4828, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=mHomePage,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462404}] I/DynamiteModule:
>   Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4
>   and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
>                     Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6 V/FA: Activity
>   resumed, time: 1585685 I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   W/atheer.booklyv: Unsupported class loader W/atheer.booklyv: Skipping
>   duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader D/FA: Logging
>   event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=mHomePage,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=5185910341027462404,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=loginActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462405}] I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey!
>   duration=916ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=1585088907737,
>   Vsync=1585705574379, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807,
>   NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1585721516670,
>   AnimationStart=1585721565670, PerformTraversalsStart=1585722412670,
>   DrawStart=1586003516670, SyncQueued=1586003568670,
>   SyncStart=1586003659670, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1586003710670,
>   SwapBuffers=1586004070670, FrameCompleted=1586005330670,
>   DequeueBufferDuration=162000, QueueBufferDuration=300000, 
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3 0 (tinfo
>   0xe2730c60) D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config
>   specified, using platform default I/AssistStructure: Flattened final
>   assist data: 3404 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11 views V/FA:
>   Inactivity, disconnecting from the service I/AssistStructure:
>   Flattened final assist data: 3428 bytes, containing 1 windows, 11
>   views W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user (
>   N72Vpxaf6dao4pSf5cvBJ1jwzGo2 ). D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state
>   listeners. D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners. V/FA:
>   Recording user engagement, ms: 21363 V/FA: Connecting to remote
>   service W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@48f31b0 V/FA: Activity paused, time:
>   1607047 D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   engagement_time_msec(_et)=21363,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=loginActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462405}] V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress I/atheer.booklyv:
>   NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 25494(1649KB) AllocSpace
>   objects, 19(632KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 580us total
>   742.771ms V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1608103 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=loginActivity,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=5185910341027462405,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=dashboardAdmin,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462406}] D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2730c60) V/FA:
>   Connection attempt already in progress D/FA: Connected to remote
>   service V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4 W/ActivityThread:
>   handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token
>   android.os.BinderProxy@7f475a4 V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms:
>   5136 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1613235 D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   engagement_time_msec(_et)=5136,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=dashboardAdmin,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462406}] V/FA: onActivityCreated
>   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1613594 D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=dashboardAdmin,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=5185910341027462406,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=approvedAdmin,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=5185910341027462407}] D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2730c60)
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3 0 (tinfo
>   0xe2730c60) W/atheer.booklyv: Long wait of 5.943ms for
>   Thread[1,tid=8309,Native,Thread*=0xe6674000,peer=0x738f9ec8,"main"]
>   suspension! D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3 0
>   (tinfo 0xe2730c60) D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver 3
>   0 (tinfo 0xe2730c60) D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcc20f240: ver
>   3 0 (tinfo 0xe2730c60) V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the
>   service E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error:
>   15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)  I/chatty:
>   uid=10086(com.example.atheer.booklyv1) Binder:8309_5 identical 3 lines
>   E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
>   I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
>   I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection
>   to gms implementation

And this is my java code

```
package com.example.atheer.booklyv1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class approvedAdmin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    DatabaseReference dref;
    ListView listview;

    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public approvedAdmin() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_approved_admin);
       listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("client");
       // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String status;
                String name;
                String email;

                Toast.makeText(approvedAdmin.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                    if (ds.hasChild("Status")){
                        status=ds.child("Status").getValue(String.class);
                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Not approved")){
                            name= ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                            list.add(name);
                            adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(approvedAdmin.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }}
                    }}
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

And this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".approvedAdmin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp">
         <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the issue you have ? Move out these two lines out of for loop scope.`adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(approvedAdmin.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move out setting up adapter code out from for loop, like below

```
for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
    if (ds.hasChild("Status")){
        status=ds.child("Status").getValue(String.class);
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Not approved")){
            name= ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(name);
        }
    }
}

adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(approvedAdmin.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You also need to change the listview id from `android:id="@android:id/list"` to `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: I tried but I faced a run time error (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference)

Comment: make sure while doing this your listview is initialized properly 'listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);' . for safer side have edited the answer.

Comment: I tried this also and I faced the same error of (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference), I am really I don't know how can I solve the problem.

Comment: I got the issue why you getting the NPE, You  need to change the listview id from `android:id="@android:id/list"` to `android:id="@+id/list"`. Have edited the answer accordingly